# Excel shared notebook - live update one sheet and other dont

Tags: excel, vba

I have a shared notebook in excel, and i want to share the notebook with my team. I have 2 sheets, one with a macro and the other one is a table. The first sheet has a form with macros to update the table in the second sheet. What i would like to do is to share the notebook and the sheet one people is not live updated but the second one is. Is this possible?

I don't know if this is possible, but i want people to fill the first sheet and the run the macro to update the second one, the second one is being update live, and the first one is almost like a local sheet

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you have tried.